# Cisco IOS - terminate a process (kill a process)

Tags: process, ios, operating-system

How do I terminate a process similarly to `kill -9 $PID`?

I would like to do the same as GNU/Linux offers: For example, a shell is running a Telnet session to a router, but later that router is powered off. Consequently, the shell is unusable. All I have to do is lookup the process ID matching `telnet $IPv4_of_router` and then issue `kill -9 $Process_ID`. This is just an example. However, how do I terminate a process?

Comment: Pretty sure this is only possible with IOS XR.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to kill a hung ip sla responder process using the following command:

```
clear sockets 122
```

where 122 is the PID for the process IP SLAs Responder which was previously using 99%+ CPU time.